# Problema de sintaxis con Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter, machine-learning

Tengo un problema de sintaxis en Jupyter Notebook, que lo uso con anaconda. Quería saber cuál es el problema. Uso Windows 10, con Python 3.8

Este es el código:

```
df = pd.read_csv(**r'C:\Users\Lupin III\Downloads\.ipynb_checkpoints\base.csv'*)
```

Este es el error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes que quitar '**r' y '*' del principio y el final de la cadena y cambiar las barras invertidas por barras normales '/'

Explico un poco más en detalle el uso de rutas en python:

- Uso no válido de rutas en python:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('c:\temp\folder\file.csv')
```

Se debe a que el caracter '\' es especial y se utiliza para tabulaciones, saltos de línea, etc. (por ejemplo \t en el ejemplo sería una tabulador)

- Uso correcto de rutas:

```py
df = pd.read_csv(r'c:\temp\folder\file.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('c:/temp/folder/file.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('c:\\temp\\folder\\file.csv')
```